# Im trying to store data in local storage but its not working for me

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, local-storage

`I am storing the data in local Storage it is working but when i refreshes the data resets, But when i turn off the react strict mode it works perfectly fine whats the issue?

```
const NotesGrid = () => {
const setNotes = useAppStore((s) => s.setNotes);
const notes = useAppStore((s) => s.notes);

const searchStr = useSearchStore((s) => s.searchStr);
const data = searchStr
? notes.filter((n) =>
    n.text.toLowerCase().includes(searchStr.toLowerCase())
  )
: notes;

useEffect(() => {
const t = localStorage.getItem("react-todoList") || "[]";
const temp = JSON.parse(t);
if (temp) {
  setNotes(temp);
}
}, []);

 useEffect(() => {
localStorage.setItem("react-todoList", JSON.stringify(notes));
 }, [notes]);

 // if (data.length === 0) return <Box>No Data</Box>;
 return (
<SimpleGrid gap={3} columns={{ sm: 1, md: 2, lg: 4, "2xl": 6 }}>
  {data.map((n) => (
    <Note note={n} key={n.id} />
  ))}
    {!searchStr && <EditingNote />}
  </SimpleGrid>
 );
};
```

I tried turning of the strict mode and the app works fine then.`

Comment: What you mean by __when i refreshes the data resets__?

Comment: from the local storage it resets